# How to write logs into multiple files?

Tags: go, logging

In Golang how you guys manage to write logs into multiple file base on the package name.

For example in my current app, I am trying to collect multiple hardware stats from different packages called Netapp, IBM etc but under the same application. So, I would like to write logs from those package in separate folder like /var/log/myapp/netapp.log and /var/log/myapp/ibm.log?

Any pointer or clue would be very helpful ?

Thanks James

Comment: I haven't seen any libraries that currently do this but I would guess you could use the call stack of the log function, looking at the prior frame and pulling the package from that?

Comment: I will try to implement.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could take is to implement the **Observer** pattern. It's a great approach when you need to make several things happen with the same input/event. In your case, logging the same input to different logs. You can find more information [here](https://github.com/tmrts/go-patterns/blob/master/behavioral/observer.md).

In a situation you described and following this [example](https://play.golang.org/p/cr8jEmDmw0), you can do following things:

1. Your different logging implementations (with different logging destination folders) can implement the `Observer` interface by putting your logging code for each logging implementation in `OnNotify` method.
2. Create an instance of `eventNotifier` and register all your logging implementations with `eventNotifier.Register` method. Something like:

   ```
     notifier := eventNotifier{
        observers: map[Observer]struct{}{},
     }

     notifier.Register(netAppLogger)

     notifier.Register(ibmLogger)
   ```
3. Use `eventNotifier.Notify` whenever and wherever you need to do logging and it will use all registered logging implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I will try and will let know, if i am able to get something.